# How to have search results from a views defined block display on page?

Tags: 7, views, search

I have created a custom search block with Views 3 in Drupal 7. I would like the results of that search be displayed in a page (like the default drupal search block) and not in the block itself (which seems to be the default behaviour for views). How do I accomplish this? I think I am missing a setting somewhere but can't find it.

Comment: you will probably have to duplicate the search block as a page, and then override the redirect for the submit in the block to point to the page

Comment: I do have a search page defined already. How do I override the submit of the block to point to the page?

Answer (score 0):

This is from a project I worked on a while ago. It uses Search Api and has a full search page at product-search/% (a Search Api view). After the redirect in the block's form submit, it places the search term into the search box text field for the search page. It's not a direct answer to your question as you will have to adapt the code if you want to use it.

```
function MODULE_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['product_search'] = array(
    'info' => 'Search Products',
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function MODULE_block_view($delta) {
  $block =  array();
  switch($delta) {
    case 'product_search':
      $block['subject'] = t('Search Products');
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('MODULE_search_products_form');
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function MODULE_search_products_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['search'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Terms to search for'),
    '#size' => 28,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Search'));

  return $form;
}

function MODULE_search_products_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_goto('product-search/' . $form_state['values']['search']);
}

function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'views_exposed_form':
      if ($form_state['view']->name=='product_search_api_view' && $form_state['view']->current_display=='page') {
        // get the view argument if defined
        if (isset($form_state['view']->args[0])) {
          // Set form filter input value to term tid
          if (!isset($form_state['input']['search_api_views_fulltext']))
            $form_state['input']['search_api_views_fulltext'] = $form_state['view']->args[0];
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```